# Get Error when i ADD CONSTRAINT ON DELETE CASCADE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I am trying to create CONSTRAINT but sql server gives me an error.

> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Product_SubCategory' on table
>   'Product' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.

and here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product] 
(
    [ProductId]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName]     NCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
    [ProductPrice]    DECIMAL (18) NOT NULL,
    [ProductQuantity] INT          NULL,
    [SubCategoryId]   INT          NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductId] ASC)
);
```

And

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_SubCategory] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([SubCategoryId]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[SubCategory] ([SubCategoryId]) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Why do you tag Oracle and MySQL?

Comment: Here is a good explanation of this error and how to get around it https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/